# ASIHttpRequest replacement and image caching

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, asihttprequest

I've been using ASIHttpRequest library for a while for downloading images and storing them for cache. Since it is deprecated already I'm looking for a replacement library.

My needs are to download a new image and to store it for cache **only and only if image has changed on server**. Otherwise to use cached image.

Is there a good and lite alternative to beloved ASIHttpRequest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure there is: [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

AFNetworking is de-facto the natural replacement of ASIHTTP. It's a lovely library and version 2.0 has just being launched.

Another great library is surely [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), which provides a lot of useful functionalities for downloading and caching images.

You are clearly free to use both in your project. I personally use `AFNetworking` for any network operation a part from images, for which I use `SDWebImage`.

Comment: Ok, I chose to use SDWebImage and looks like it does what I need. Thanks.

Comment: SDWebImage is very convenient especially with the progressive image download. But it’s based out of **NSURLConnection** ( even in the latest version 3.7.5 ) and we know that that is deprecated starting iOS 9. NSURLSession has been around for 3+ years now. Surprisingly SDWebImage has still not migrated to NSURLSession. 

See the SDWebImage: [Migration to NSURLSessions](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/1291).

**AFNetworking 3.0** is completely based on NSURLSession. So I think AfNetworking would a better choice than SDWebImage.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a library to handle image downloads and caching, I recommend [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

It includes a category class on `UIImageView` as well as `SDWebImageManager` if you're just looking to download images and not immediately place them in a `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

[This link would help you it will download it and next time it will take images from cache](https://github.com/nicholjs/SDWebImage-with-loading-progress/blob/master/SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h)

Comment: Does it check if image changed?

Comment: Yes whenever you app starts it takes from url but when your app is running and u come to that view it will not call url but take it from cache. so during that when app is running it can`t check image is changed but when your app starts it checks.